# Как в юнити создать объект если касаются 2 других?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Хочу сделать игру, но столкнулся с проблемой. У меня есть код который создает яйцо из префаба. Префаб яйца имеет коллайдер и тег "Egg". Я хочу создать код, который будет узнавать касаются ли 2 яйца. И если они касаются, то они должны исчезнуть а на ихнем месте должен появится ОДИН другой объект. Проблема в, том что если я создам простой код, который будет проверять касание и повешу его на префаб с яйцом, то когда они соприкоснутся от каждого из яиц будет по одному новому объекту. Потому что на префабе яйца есть этот код и он будет срабатывать одновременно на двух яйцах сразу. Вопрос: как сделать чтобы был к примеру один код на пустом объекте, который узнавал касаются ли 2 яйца и создавал на ихнем месте один другой объект?

Answer (score 0):

Данный код должен решать проблему:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class OneCollisionExecutor : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool _hasExecuted = false;

    public void MarkAsExecuted()
    {
        _hasExecuted = true;
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if(!_hasExecuted && collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Egg"))
        {
            collision.gameObject.GetComponent<OneCollisionExecutor>().MarkAsExecuted();

            InstantiateSomething();

            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    private void InstantiateSomething()
    {
        //Код создания необходимого объекта
    }
}
```

Comment: Этот код нужно прикрепить к префабу яйца?

Comment: Да. Я думаю, это достаточно очевидно.

Comment: В начале я так и сделал, но потом усомнился и решил переспросить. Так как код не заработал.

Comment: `private void InstantiateSomething()
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Ok");
    }
}`
я добавил это в код, но в консоль ничего не выводиться и объекты не исчезают.

Comment: И если что это 2д проект.

Comment: @Hlib если вы этот метод не вызвали, то он и не сработает. Переведите его название, это просто пример.

Comment: Огромное Вам всем спасибо!!!!! Все заработало! Проблема была в том что код который мне отправили был рассчитан на 3д проект. Но это моя вина что не точно задал вопрос и не указал в нем что это 2д игра. Я его изменил и теперь все работает как надо!

Comment: @Wind F. И еще один вопрос. Проблема в том, что если объект на котором прикреплен код соприкасается сразу два таких же, то с трех объектов будет 2 новых. Нужно сделать какую-то проверку на количество соприкосновений.